# Raspberry Pi SMBus support combined data transmission?

Tags: python, i2c

I am trying to use the ACS764 Hall effect current sensor with Raspberry Pi. This sensor will sense the current and return its value via the chip built-in I2C interface. I had connected the circuit according to the specification. On my Raspberry Pi Python code I can write and read data to/from the sensor however the data I read alway the same value.

Below is my simple code to read the sensor:

```
import datetime
import smbus
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT) #Connected to the ACS764 Freeze pin

bus=smbus.SMBus(1)

#Freeze the data
GPIO.output(37, True)

#Read the values
bus.write_byte(0x60, 0x00) #Simulate the combined data transmission format
data=bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x60, 0x00)
print data

#Unfreeze the data
GPIO.output(37, False)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

However when I run the script the value alway show the same even I had changed the current to be sensed value.

```
pi@Raspberry:~ $ python i2cAcs764.py 
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
```

According to the ACS764 specification, to read the sensor value, I need to use the "combined data transmission" format. However, I didn't find any function in the Python SMBus library that allow me to use the combined data transmission, therefore at the moment I use the "bus.write_byte" function to simulate the "combined data transmission". Below is the screen capture of the specification.

[ACS764 Datasheet Snapshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbno9.png)

My question now is how can I use the Python SMBus I2C library to perform the "combined data transmission" reading of the ACS764 chip?

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: The protocol specified in your datasheet screenshot seems considerably more complex than what you're doing in your python script

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it completely but this is how I read it... MASTER: sends a sequence of start bit + slave address + write bit (a zero) + source register address. MASTER: sends another sequence but this time start bit + slave address + read bit(1). SLAVE: sends data byte 1. MASTER: pulls SDA low. SLAVE: sends data byte 2. MASTER: pulls SDA low. SLAVE: sends data byte 3. MASTER: sends stop bit. That's 5 separate transmissions from MASTER/python and 3 from the SLAVE/hall sensor in response. A lot of back and forth (commands, data and ACKs). Using a library would be a lot easier, I'm sure

Answer (score 1):

After google for a few days I finally found a solution to my question above. The answer is that Raspberry I2C interface does support "combined data transmission" (aka Repeated Start) but it is not enable by default. You need to enable the setting by the following command.

```
sudo su -
echo -n 1 > /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined
exit
```

Please refer to [i2c repeated start transactions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=15840&start=25)
 for more information.

Base on the smbus specification the function that support the repeated start is i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data(), in Python library it is call read_i2c_block_data().

Please refer to the [SMBus Protocol Summary](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol) for more details.

Below is my sample code that read data from ACS764 Hall effect sensor chip that required repeated start.

```
import datetime
import smbus
import time

bus=smbus.SMBus(1)

# Write setting parameter to the chip
data = [0x02, 0x02, 0x02]
bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x60, 0x04, data)

# Read the data out of the chip that require Repeated Start
data=bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x60, 0x00)
print data
```

I was happy to find the solution and hope that those who face the same issue can get help from this post. Thank you all!